# Outputting text fields into PDF file using FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

On the first page(page1.php) which is an HTML form,content such as this is present:

```
<input type ="text" size="25"   name="first_name" />
```

Form action is set as this: `<form action="printpdf.php" method="post" id="print">`

I would like to create a pdf file using FPDF to take whatever is entered in the '`first_name`' text field and be able to output in a PDF preferably by using `$POST` command in PHP.
Any ideas on how I can do this using FPDF?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: You might save yourself some work by using DOMPDF: http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

index.html:

```
<form action="printpdf.php" method="post" id="print">
    <input type="text" size="25" name="first_name" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

printpdf.php:

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 16);
$pdf->Cell(40, 10, $_POST['first_name']);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Note that this is taken almost directly from the [FPDF tutorial](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto1.htm).

If you're doing a lot with PDFs, you may consider using [DOMPDF](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/).

Comment: Thanks for your help.It solved the problem.I'm pretty much learning the way FPDF works from scratch.Once again thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some good example on:
http://www.fpdf.org/

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,$_POST['first_name']);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```